# Only getting upto 6Mbps on ethernet even though link speed is 100 Mbps

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, lan, wired-networking

So I have a 100Mbps internet connection , which when connected to wirelessly delivers the full speed. However when connected to my laptop through an ethernet adaptor , I dont get more the 6Mbps . On my other device which has an ethernet port it also gives the full 100Mbps . This made me think that maybe the adapter was at fault . However on checking it seems that it is configure to 100 Mbps full duplex as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7XIO.png) .Any ideas as to what could be wrong ?

EDIT:

> lsusb -t details -

```
Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=, Driver=dm9601, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

Comment: Try a new driver for the existing card. Try a new USB to Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Can these adapters advertise incorrect link speeds?

Comment: High quality adapters should provide top speed.

Comment: Is it a USB adapter? To what sort of USB port is it connected? What does `lsusb -t` reports?

Comment: Are you certain you're getting 6Mbps, not 6MBps? The latter would be about right for a 100Mbps connection.

Comment: It's a usb 2.0 to ethernet adapter .but i tried on 2.0 and 3.2 ports . Didn't work out. And yeah it's definitely 6Mbps

Comment: The line with `Driver=dm9601, 12M` says its maximum speed is 12 Mbps, so it isn't as bad as it seems. Do you have another device that you could try the adapter in?

Comment: Yeah . I realised the adapter was capped . Even tho it says its usb 2.0 it actually uses usb 1.1 . Returned it and i'm going to get a new one . 
For future reference for others -  don't trust adapters with the rd9700 drivers . They all seem to be misleading according to the internet .

Answer (score 0):

First level of fault finding:

1. Disturbance sources just beside the cable?
2. Any visible damage on cables?
3. How about the connectors?
4. Replace cable regardless (there might be INVISIBLE damage)
5. Network adapters ok?

Note that a shielded cable is similar to a water hose; you cannot bend it beyond a certain limit (not very tight bends) without causing transmission loss or even permanent damage. Actual smallest bend depends on cable make and type.

Please also keep in mind the difference between

- Mega BITS per second (Mbps) and
- Mega BYTES per second (MBps)

Sanity: Mbps-numbers are about 10 times higher than MBps; so 6MBps is approximately 60Mbps.

---

General electric fault: when just one combination shows the symptom:

An adapter (or whatever) may be "weak" in such way that when connected to a specific device that requires a strong mating, it fails to deliver the expected result (at any level; showing limited, intermittent, random function or full failure).

*The EXACT cause for such situations may vary quite dramatically.*

In this case one might consider either or both of the devices faulty.

Comment: Like I said , when connected to a different device without the adapter it provides the full speed . Just not with the adapter on my device . And yeah . 6 megaBITS/s

Comment: Added some general text - remember that we do not live in a perfect world.